# Very Simple RE: New Lines in PHP when sourcing mySQL in a form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, echo

I print data into a form, however can't find the right syntax to produce a new line after each echo.. Anyone able to help me out?

```
echo 'Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled /> ";
echo 'Forename: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['forename']. "\" disabled />";
echo 'Email Address: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['emailAddress']. "\" disabled />"; 
echo 'Preference ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['dob']. "\" disabled />"; 
echo 'Seat Number: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['seatNo']. "\" disabled />"; 
echo 'Group ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['groupID']. "\" disabled />";
```

Where would the \n apply?

Many thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is HTML you should use `<br>` to force a newline to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

PHP only parses "\n" when it's in double quotes. Otherwise it's taken literally; if you want to have a new line in the source code use `echo "\n"`. for an HTML line break use `echo "<br>"`

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should) use label tag for form field label:

```
echo '<label class="someClass">Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled /></label>";
echo '<label class="someClass">Forename: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['forename']. "\" disabled /></label>";
```

Class is optional.

Alternative syntax would be:

```
echo '<label for="surname" class="someClass">Surname: </label>
<input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled />";
```

The you can use css to apply styles so you don't need `<br />` tags:

```
form label{
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 3px 2px 3px;
  font-size:1.1em;
}

//if you want to group different labels visually you can do it with classes
.someClass{
  color:#CCC;
}
```

The not so correct way of doing almost the same thing would be:

```
echo 'Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled /><br />";
echo 'Forename: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['forename']. "\" disabled /><br />";
```

But then you lose the possibility to apply different styles easily by css and lose the trust of visually impaired users...

Worth checking migh also be PHP function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line after each input you should use the `<br />` tag, your code would look like this:

```
echo 'Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['surname'].  "\" disabled /><br />";
echo 'Forename: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['forename']. "\" disabled /><br />";
echo 'Email Address: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['emailAddress']. "\" disabled /><br />"; 
echo 'Preference ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['dob']. "\" disabled /><br />"; 
echo 'Seat Number: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['seatNo']. "\" disabled /><br />"; 
echo 'Group ID: <input type="text" name="surname" value="'.$row['groupID']. "\" disabled /><br />";
```